# IOS: Justify text in UILabel not working in UI

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, text-justify

I want to align justify my text in `UILabel` but it seem like not work. However, another align is left,right,center work.
I'm using XCode 7.2. I have tested on simulator and real device but it produce same problem

**Align Justify**
[image]

My text:

```
Don't worry, your data will not be sold.Don't worry,your data wills not be sold. Connecting your accounts will benefit your E score and your profile viewing experience. Don't worry, your data will not be sold.Don't worry, your data wills not be sold. Connecting your accounts will benefit your ECT score and your profile viewing experience.
```

with font : `Helvetica Neue 13.0` and trailing/leading: 10

Same problem if I use align in here to justify text
[image]

I don't know why this happened to me. Please give me some instruction for fix it. Any help would be great appreciated

Comment: It's not suppose to work on the last line. Everything is normal.

Comment: In first look, i thought you answering or questioning.. because your post says you already getting what you asking.. lol ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like a bug of UILabel,but you can fix it with a tiny change in your storyboard.
Click the ***more*** button in the same line of NSTextAlignments,add a little Head Indent ,such as `0.1`  .
[image]

Your UILabel will work just fine.
[image]

Comment: thank you so much. Change the `indent` value make my `UILabel` jutify

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Here is what I get from the simulator:
[image]

What I've done:

1. Drag & drop an UILabel on the storyboard and add some constrains, and colours as well.
2. Set the text as "attributed"
3. Put your text in the text field.
4. Click on justify.
5. Change the police
6. Numbers of lines 0.

At this point you should have this:
[image]

Now from the storyboard to your controller add an IBOutlet (Ctrl + drag it to the top of your controller). It should be like this:
[image]

Now add some code in your viewDidLoad fct:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.Justified

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: label.text!, attributes: [ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(float: 0)
            ])

        label.attributedText = attributedString
        label.numberOfLines = 0
```

The last thing to do is to run your simulator to see if it does what you are expected:
[image]

P.S: With xCode 7.2 works definitely. It works for me on both version.

Comment: which version of xcode use using? how you achieve it.

Comment: Version 7.3 (7D175) but should work as well with version 7.2. Juste one minute, I m typing more info ;)

Comment: i'm sure 100% that not work in Xcode `Version 7.2 (7C68)`. i will update Xcode now

Comment: i apologize for my confusion. it still happens

Comment: @PhanVănLinh: no worries, have a look at my added screenshot.

Comment: @KeyMarker00 I have update my post, with my Xcode image

Comment: I have to go home now. I will check your update later. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Ah! because it's already justified. If you stretch your label box a bit more you will see that the word "accounts" will be on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution to solve my problem right now. I set the `alignment justified` for my `UILabel` programmatically and it work

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
            paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

    NSDictionary *attribute = @{
                                        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraph,
                                        NSFontAttributeName: self.describesLabel.font,
                                        NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]
                                        };
    NSAttributedString *attributeMessage = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.describesLabel.text attributes:attribute];
    self.describesLabel.attributedText = attributeMessage;
```

Comment: Hi Phan. This is the same solution I've given you but yours is in Obj-C. A bit of recognition would be gread ;(

Comment: @KeyMaker00 I miss your Swift code. It same my code in `Obj-C` right?. I don't know swift, sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Don't use attributed text just use Plain text and select all the text and make it justify. I am facing the same problem fixed it by changing attributed to plain text in Storyboard.
If it doesn't work then you have to fix it by code :-

Using Attributed Text:-

```
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.new;
 paragraphStyle.alignment                = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

 NSDictionary *attrsDictionary           = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:yourFont,NSFontAttributeName,paragraphStyle,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];

 NSAttributedString *attributeMessage    = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourTextString attributes:attrsDictionary];
 self.yourLabel.attributedText           = attributeMessage;
```

Using Plain Text :-

```
self.yourLabel.textAlignment             = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
self.yourLabel.font                      = yourFont;
self.yourLabel.text                      = yourTextString;
```

Hope It helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically if its not working from storyboard or nib

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;


NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your text here"];
                                                             attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                         paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName ,
                                                                         [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName,
                                                                         nil]];

self.yourLabel.attributedText = string;
```